Nearly identical Docker-compose files: one works, one does not
Running Ubuntu Server 22.04 clean/blank. Everything update/upgrade.
Running portainer and traefik. Have a total of nine stacks running 15 containers.
Looking to have two installations of PHPMyAdmin. The docker-compose files are nearly identical yet one is not working. "Orange" works. "Plum" does not. Here's the orange compose file:
services:
  sql_admin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: sql_admin
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: sql_admin
    ports:
      - 8030:443
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_admin.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_admin.rule=Host(`orange.example.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_admin.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    environment:
      - "PMA_ARBITRARY=1"
    networks:
      - traffic-network

networks:
  traffic-network:
    external: true

Here is the plum compose file:
services:
  sql_myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: sql_myadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: sql_myadmin
    ports:
      - 8002:443
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myadmin.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myadmin.rule=Host(`plum.example.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myadmin.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    environment:
      - "PMA_ARBITRARY=1"
    networks:
      - traffic-network

networks:
  traffic-network:
    external: true

orange works perfectly.
Plum returns "this site cannot provide a secure connection"
When I look at the logs, orange shows a series of GET commands (I believe from Apache):
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Apr/2024:00:45:42 +0000] "GET /vendor/js.cookie.js HTTP/1.1" 404 440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; ONEPLUS A3010) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.111 Mobile Safari/537.36"

172.20.0.2 - - [29/Apr/2024:00:45:42 +0000] "GET /vendor/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Symbian/3; Series60/5.2 NokiaE6-00/021.002; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) NokiaBrowser/7.3.1.16 Mobile Safari/533.4 3gpp-gba"

172.20.0.2 - - [29/Apr/2024:00:45:42 +0000] "GET /vendor/tracekit.js HTTP/1.1" 404 440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/14.0.825.0 Chrome/14.0.825.0 Safari/535.1"

172.20.0.2 - - [29/Apr/2024:00:45:41 +0000] "GET /vendor/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25"

looking at the plum log file shows an Apache error/warning:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.16. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

My understanding is that specific log entry is supposed to be a "warning" and should not cause failure.
According to this post from a few years ago (which I have to acknowledge I don't fully understand the recommended answer) simple solution would be to add "localhost" to the Apache configuration file. But such a solution doesn't explain why orange is working and plum is not.
Perhaps this is just one of those things where it's better to just do what works instead of screaming at an inanimate object about how it is supposed to be.

If you're serving on port 443, that's usually HTTP over TLS.  How are you providing TLS certificates to your application?  This setup seems like you're just trying to run a couple of prebuilt containers but not writing code per se; another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask this class of question.
